# Format of activate_time in Gtk.Menu

Tags: python, gtk

What is the format of the parameter `activate_time` in Python GTK+ when using `Gtk.Menu.popup()` method?

I have tried using `int(time.time())` but I get a traceback saying an integer is required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I can use `gtk.get_current_event_time()` to get a reasonable timestamp matching what Gtk looks like it expects.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is a complete solution, but `time.time()` [returns a float](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time), try casting to an int and see what happens.

EDIT:
After consulting the source docs, I found this tidbit:

> The button and activate_time  values should be the mouse button that was pressed to trigger the menu popup and the time the button was pressed. These values can usually be retrieved from the "button_press_event".

Perhaps this will be more helpful than my first attempt.

I also found [this C snipet in the C docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkMenu.html#GtkMenu.description), it has `popup()` being called in a signal handler (that is how they get a "button_press_event".

Comment: but I did specify I was using `int(time.time())` ;-)

Comment: whoops, should try reading some time...  It's a shame pygtk doesn't have any docs, it would sure help in situations like this!

Comment: been googling like crazy on this issue!!